# Error : <table_name> specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, erd

[image]

I want to update tot_sales attribute
tot_sales to sum of order_price's of all orders handled by the salesman

I wrote this update query. but it gives the error

> #1093 - Table 'salesman' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and >as a separate source for data

```
UPDATE salesman
SET salesman.tot_sales = (SELECT SUM(orders.order_price)
                          FROM orders
                          INNER JOIN salesman ON orders.emp_id = salesman.emp_id
                          GROUP BY salesman.emp_id
                          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your approach, use a *correlated subquery* rather than *aggregation*:

```
UPDATE salesman s
    SET s.tot_sales = (SELECT SUM(o.order_price)
                       FROM orders o
                       WHERE o.emp_id = s.emp_id
                      );
```

This would often be written as:

```
UPDATE salesman s LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT o.emp_id, SUM(o.order_price) as total_price
        FROM orders o
        GROUP BY o.emp_id
       ) o
       ON o.emp_id = s.emp_id
    SET s.tot_sales = o.total_price;
```